# How to check how long would be my next failed review audit ban?

Tags: support, review-suspension

How to check how long would be my next failed review audit ban?

Comment: I thought it was communicated to you when you attempted to enter the queues?  Or are you trying to plan how long you'll be banned for the *next* time it happens?

Comment: If you keep getting banned, maybe it's time to think about not doing reviews.

Comment: I just do not remember it was some time ago and actually I do not fully understand the system.  As I understand ban period could decline after some time and want to trace it.

Comment: check on your own review history with the consensus userscript: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251508/158100 (disclaimer: I wrote the userscript)

Answer (score 27):

There is no visible place to check, and it could vary based on when you fail an audit and who applies the ban.

You have recently been banned for 2 days, 4 days, and 8 days by the system. If you were to fail another audit in the near future, the system would automatically escalate that to 16 days (and so on after that).

However, if a moderator saw reviews that demonstrated a pattern of inattentiveness in the review queues, we can hand down bans of up to a year. Generally, if I saw someone who had been banned three times recently, and decided that they needed to be banned again, I would escalate to 30 days, then 60 days, then 365.

I highly recommend doing what you can such that you don't have to worry about any of the above.

Comment: Thank you for all except last. Somehow there in Meta people can't be "less personal" as code of conduct ask them.  Next time I would be glad to read smth like "I highly recommend everybody ..."

Comment: This is typically a case where the algorithmical system is enough and... I can't formulate anything which wouldn't violate the Coc